# knitr: print text but get rid of verbatim in the tex file

Tags: r, knitr, verbatim

I am using knitr to produce automatic reports of my studies.
I want to print or not print some text depending on different variables in the final document.
I got rid of the "##" using comment=NA, but knitr put everyting between a verbatim class in the tex file.

I am calling knitr via a R script:

```
INITIATION = T
rmarkdown::render("main.Rmd")
```

in main.rdm, I have:

````
```{r, results:asis, comment=NA,echo=FALSE}
if (INITIATION){
  #print (as.character(Initiation_form$Commentspre))
  print ("testing that")
}

```

`r Initiation_form$Commentspre`
````

which gives me in the tex file:

```
\begin{verbatim}
[1] "testing that"
\end{verbatim}
testing that
```

the inline text works, but I cannot put it inside a loop or a if argument...
as a bonus, how can I get rid of the [1]

Comment: try using results="asis"

Answer (score 3):

Use `cat()` instead of `print()` to remove the `[1]`.

Use `results = 'asis'` instead of `results:asis`

Comment: thanks, it did it. I was getting mad for such a simple trick.